# No Machine: physical device forwarding

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-access, nomachine

Is there anyway on No Machine to allow the server machine to have access to client devices, such as the webcam and wireless card of the viewing machine? I can only find the reverse process online.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a guide on the NoMachine website](https://www.nomachine.com/DT10K00060#4.3) which gives you your answer.

Here's the content of the original guide as suggested by the moderator:

> **4.3. Connect a USB Device**
>
> Share devices plugged into your local computer (client) with the
>   remote computer (server) and vice-versa. Access USB external drives,
>   USB webcams and microphones for VOIP support, scanners, barcode
>   readers, and more.
>
> E.g. Attaching an external drive from the local computer to the remote
>   desktop.
>
> Step 1 – Plug in your USB drive on your local desktop
>
> Step 2 - Connect to the remote/virtual desktop
>
> Step 3 - Open the menu panel (Ctrl-Alt-0) and select the external
>   drive from 'Local devices' (Fig. 9)
>
> Step 4 – Click Done. It will show up in your remote drives/devices
>   when you next browse them on the remote host
>
> If you wish to access a drive which is already plugged in to your
>   remote computer, follow steps 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Thank you. My build-in webcam doesn't come up as a local device, and I believe it is USB. Is there a way to fix that? What about a wifi card, would that be under network ports?